# Journey builder decision split, calculate [Current Date/Time] Minus [Date/Time Field] with minutes precision

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

In Journey builder, decision split block, is it possible to make decision based on the value of [Current Date/Time] Minus [Date/Time Field] with precision to minutes.

We can compare a value with "today" or today minus/plus #days. However, there is no precision to minute. Are there any work around that you have seen?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen a solution to this problem but I believe it's possible to achieve if you handle the logic with SQL and use an automation schedule type for your journey.

The SQL uses DATEDIFF to set a boolean variable

```
SELECT *,
CASE 
WHEN DATEDIFF(MI, [DateVar], GETDATE()) < 0 THEN 'TRUE'
ELSE 'FALSE' 
END AS EligbleForJourney
FROM [DeName]
```

Set schedule type to Automation and attach it to the automation with the SQL and use the boolean in the decision split.
Should work in theory. Let me know if it's sufficient for your problem.

Comment: Thanks @[August Rimmen] that looked promising for me too. Unfortunately I am running the journey based on mobile event as an entry source so I cannot switch it to Automation Entry Schedule source :'(

Comment: @KhoaNguyen. 

Alternatively, you could consider setting a current time variable with an SQL and use the compare attribute function in the decision split to compare it to the other data variable (both should be nonnullable).
As you cannot run an automation more than once an hour, you can add the sql multiple times to the same automation divided by short wait times which in total add up to a bit less than 1 hour. This is not a recommended method though.

 Note that for it to work proberly it I believe it is neccessary to map the variables in data designer. Hope it makes sense :)

Comment: Thanks August for this valuable bit: "add the sql multiple times to the same automation divided by short wait times which in total add up to a bit less than 1 hour."